# Adjust Logging level for apache commons logging?

Tags: java, java.util.logging, apache-commons-logging

I have a simple console app which uses apache's PDFBox library, which in turn uses commons logging. I'm getting a lot of junk messages in my console which I'd like to suppress:

> Feb 15, 2011 3:56:40 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
>   INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EI

In my code, I've tried to reset the log levels to no avail:

```
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.pdfbox.util").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("org.apache.pdfbox").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Despite these settings, the messages are still showing up on the console. Retrieving the log object from Commons logging doesn't help either, since it doesn't seem to have a way to set the level.

Is there a way to suppress these messages programmatically? Or do I need to add a config file?

Answer (score 10):

Commons-logging is only a logging-facade, meaning it doesn't provide the code which actually writes the logdata to e.g., disk. What you need to change is the configuration for the actual logging implementation (such as `logback`, `log4j`, etc.). If no such library is found it defaults to `java.util.logging`.

I would recommend putting e.g., [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) in the classpath and add a [log4j.xml](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/log4j/log4j-xml.shtml) configuration file in your classpath. The mere presence of `log4j` in the classpath is in this case enough to initialize it. Log4j can also be configured [programmatically](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

Comment: I am using java logging (i.e. I have no other logging library present). And yet it seems to be ignoring the specification of level on the Java.util.logger.

Comment: You can with a [properties](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util.logging/how-to-configure-a-logger-default-values-with-a-properties.html) file, although I generally advice [against](http://java.sys-con.com/node/48541) java.util.logging.

Comment: `slf4j` is also a logging facade, not a logging implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
String[] loggers = { "org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine",
        "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont" };
for (String logger : loggers) {
  org.apache.log4j.Logger logpdfengine = org.apache.log4j.Logger
         .getLogger(logger);
  logpdfengine.setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you have no time to figure out which Logging implementation is used underneath by the Apache commons-logging, try to disable all that are in you classpath. Following code tests three implementations.

If any of the lines doesn't compile, do not add the dependency! Just remove the line.

```
String[] loggers = { "org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine",
    "org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont", "httpclient.wire.header" , "httpclient.wire.content"
for (String ln : names) {
  // Try java.util.logging as backend
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ln).setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);

  // Try Log4J as backend
  org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(ln).setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN);

  // Try another backend
  Log4JLoggerFactory.getInstance().getLogger(ln).setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Apache commons-logging uses some other logging framework underneath (`java.util.logging` or Log4J), you have to investigate which one it uses on your project and set proper logging levels there.

Comment: I am using java logging (i.e. I have no other logging library present). And yet it seems to be ignoring the specification of level on the Java.util.logger.