# Remove PDFBox system.out.print

Tags: java, pdfbox, system.out

I would like to know how console remove an output from a third-part library. I already removed some warnings with static block System.setProperty, but Pdfbox is printing around 100 lines of output, as I'm testing other things with the console, I'd like to remove them, they looks like:

```
 [main] DEBUG , org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser
 and these: 
 [main] DEBUG org.apache.fontbox.util.autodetect.FontFileFinder - found checkFontfile
```

Comment: adjust log level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466610/disabling-logging-on-pdfbox

Comment: Are you using some IBM environment of which I forgot the name?

Comment: Just using org.apache.pdfbox dependency.